# R: Vars - Column list for use in loop/function/apply

Tags: r, function, dataframe, lapply

I am trying to do the following code:

```
vars <- c("var1", "var2", "var3") #These corresponds to the names of the columns in my DF

Test <- lapply(DF[, vars], function(x) lm(x~var_x))
```

I want to be able to use the assigned value "vars" which includes all my desired columns (variables) so that I don't have to actually mention each column one at a time in my code. But the following code gives me this error:

```
 Error in `[.data.frame`(DF, , c(vars)) : undefined columns selected
```

How should I apply "vars" in order for this to work as desired?

Answer (score 3):

Here, the output from `lapply` is a the value of that column.  May be we need to pass the column name and create the formula

```
lapply(vars,  function(x) lm(as.formula(paste0(x "~ var_x")), data = DF))
```

Or another option is `reformulate` to create the `formula`

```
lapply(vars, function(x) lm(reformulate("var_x", response = x), data = DF))
```

---

In order to get the output in a single table, we can use `tidy` or `glance` from `broom`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
map_dfr(setNames(vars, vars) ~ 
            lm(reformulate("var_x", response = .x), data = DF) %>%
            tidy, .id = 'grp')
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work (the last line of code). Do you know how to manipulate that code for these 2 scenarios? 1) var_x = dummy variable, I want to apply the code when var_x = 1 and var_x = 0.  2) How do I get a certain statistics for all variables out in order to show a few statistics (e.g coefficient) in a table. Now it is only given as a list and it won't let me convert to data frame either.

Comment: @Andycode if you want output in a table, use `broom` i.e. `library(broom);do.call(rbind, lapply(vars, function(x) tidy(lm(reformulate("var_x", response = x), data = DF))))`